Resizable Canvas with Web Components Growing to Infinity
I'm trying to create a resizable <canvas> with Web Components, but, for some reason, in the way I'm doing (with ResizeObserver), the initial height grows from zero to infinite on the outer <div> (in the example below, I capped the height with CSS' max-height).
Is my initial setting ok? Is there a simpler way of doing this?
I did try using this.canvas.height = this.parentElement.clientHeight instead of this.canvas.height = this.height, but the results were even weirder.


const hookbanContainerTemplate = document.createElement("template")
hookbanContainerTemplate.innerHTML = "<slot></slot>"

class HookbanContainer extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    shadowRoot.appendChild(hookbanContainerTemplate.content.cloneNode(true))
  }
}

class HookbanBackground extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["width", "height"]
  }

  constructor(width = 100, height = 100) {
    super()
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    shadowRoot.appendChild(this.canvas)

    this.drawBackground()
  }

  drawBackground() {
    this.canvas.width = this.width
    this.canvas.height = this.height

    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
    if (!ctx) return

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.fillRect(
      0,
      0,
      this.canvas.width,
      this.canvas.height
    )
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(
    name,
    _oldValue,
    newValue
  ) {
    switch (name) {
      case "width":
        this.width = parseFloat(newValue)
        break
      case "height":
        this.height = parseFloat(newValue)
        break
      default:
    }

    this.drawBackground()
  }
}

customElements.define("hookban-container", HookbanContainer)
customElements.define("hookban-background", HookbanBackground)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hookban</title>

    <style>
      body {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      #demo-container {
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;

        height: fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
        max-height: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="demo-container">
      <hookban-container>
        <hookban-background />
      </hookban-container>
    </div>

    <script>
      const observer = new ResizeObserver((mutations) => {
        const { height: newHeight, width: newWidth } = mutations[0].contentRect

        const hookbanBackground = document.querySelector("hookban-background")

        hookbanBackground.setAttribute("height", newHeight)
        hookbanBackground.setAttribute("width", newWidth)
      })

      const hookbanContainer = document.querySelector("div")
      observer.observe(hookbanContainer)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



(I don't know why that snippet is giving the error message ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications, that doesn't happen to me locally.)

The code in this question is being used in this project.


First of all: do not do DOM stuff in the constructor, do it in the connectedCallback. When you do createElement("hookban-container") (theres is no DOM, element is created in memory) OR execute the code before DOM was parsed, it will error. I honestly have no clue this will fix your errors, but at least it will be a correct Web Component

I was originally using those inside connectedCallback, but then I put them in the constructor and got no errors locally, which I thought was weird, but it simplified the  code a bit, and I left it so.

This probably doesn't help much, but the code in this question is being used in this project.

One weird thing is that setting height/width to fit-content, or setting max-height/max-width to 300px seem to be where things stop working (#demo-container CSS). If I simply setup as just height/width to 300px, then things work as expected pretty much.

In your example the observed height is 4px bigger than the element you are resizing. Thus when the attribute is set the size changes and a new resize is triggered. Repeating the cycle, and so on, and on.  Where the 4pxs comes from I can not see, but if you subtract the erroneous 4px from the height hookbanBackground.setAttribute("height", newHeight - 4) you stop the setting triggering a new resize and all is good again (except your knowledge as to WHY?)

I started over; you want a resizeable canvas
I created one self-contained Web Component <full-size-canvas>
key issue was the ResizeObserver fires when the size changed; thus creating an endless loop.
You have to refactor it to your needs. Extract canvas to this.canvas and make updateCanvas a Method.
One behavior to be aware offf: If you have observedAttributes, to init the attribute the attributeChangedCallback will fire before the connectedCallback; you can check this.isConnected if the connectedCallback fired yet.


<full-size-canvas></full-size-canvas>

<script>
  customElements.define("full-size-canvas", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let width = 200, height = 80, canvas;
      const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
      const updateCanvas = (color = "blue") => {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width  = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      }
      Object.assign(this.style, {
        display  : "inline-block",
        resize   : "both",
        border   : "1px solid black",
        overflow : "auto"
      });
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open"})
          .append(
              createElement("style", {
                 innerHTML: `canvas {vertical-align:top}`,
              }),
              canvas = createElement("canvas")
          );
      updateCanvas("beige");
      let observer = new ResizeObserver((mutations) => {
        ({ width, height } = mutations[0].contentRect);
        if ((canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height)) {
          observer.unobserve(this); // do not observe on repaint
          updateCanvas();
          // Re-enable the observer after the current call stack is clear
          // also prevents Observer undelivered notifications warning
          setTimeout(() => observer.observe(this));
        }// resized
      });// resizeObserver
      observer.observe(this);
    }// connectedCCallback
  })
</script>



Addendum
Here is the refactored Web Component: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/8a2fq9nb/

Here is the refactored Web Component: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/8a2fq9nb/
